# NullPointer Exception while performing string split

Tags: java, file, io, nullpointerexception

I am getting input from a file. The file has two columns. I want to store each column in an array. This is what i'm doing.

```
   String strArr;

    for(int x=0;x<=m;x++){  // m is the number of lines to parse

      strArr = bufReader.readLine(); 
     String[] vals=strArr.split("\\s+ ");
      System.out.println(strArr);

    nodei[x]=Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
    nodej[x]=Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);

      }
```

I encounter NullPointerException at

`String[] vals=strArr.split("\\s+ ");`

How do I resolve?

Comment: Your question may already have an answer here: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

if `strArr` is null, and you call `.split` on it, it will throw a null pointer. You can check if null before using `.split`.

```
String strArr;

for(int x=0;x<=m;x++){  // m is the number of lines to parse

  strArr = bufReader.readLine(); 
  if (strArr != null) {
      String[] vals=strArr.split("\\s+ ");
      System.out.println(strArr);

      nodei[x]=Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
      nodej[x]=Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
  }
}
```